# My engine turns over, but fails to start unless bumped

Tags: starting

Car will not start on key, engine turns over. No fault code on diagnostic tester. Petrol engine. Vehicle will bump start, and also start with jump leads.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please edit your question and include what type of vehicle you're talking about? (ie: year/make/model) As well, your question is very vague. Any more details would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that it starts using the key if you have jump leads connected to another car battery?

Comment: Does the starter sound slower when trying to start without jump leads than it does with jump leads?

Comment: Remove your battery cables from battery and thoroughly clean them and battery terminals with battery terminal cleaners or a wire brush and see what happens.

Comment: Test your battery voltage with a multimeter.